# Test for convergence from the graph

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Is it possible to test the convergence of a series from the graph of the function?

Is there any geometrical representation of convergence and divergence?

Comment: No, because graphs can be wrong.

Comment: @zhw. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

No, what if its convergent series but to a very very very large number ?

for example : $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln^{10^{100}} (k)}{k^2}$

which is convergent but its very hard to any software to show it graphically that its convergent.